# what's the meaning of EJB view ( local view ,remote view, no-interface view)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I used to understand it means "Interface".

a local client can operate the EJB by local interface, so client can view local interface, is this the "View" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local view is the interface you want to expose to local clients.

Remote View is the interface you want to expose for remote clients, perhaps with less functionality.

No interface view, I believe, is just automatically generates an EJB view based on the methods of the class.

The "view" is what is going to be exposed based on the EJB lookup.

Answer (score 1):

A view is an early term and more abstract term for what we now generally refer to as proxy.

A view goes beyond an interface. Yes, for a local and remote view the associated interfaces are the type of the proxy but they are not the bean itself. With the no interface view, the type of the proxy is the bean class, but the proxy is not the bean instance. If the bean class has instance variables, they will be present on the proxy as well, but they will be useless and if no constructor is used they will not be assigned a non-default value either.